# Open Additional Fragment

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a way to open a second Fragment Page? (ie. open multiple fragment pages at the same time)

I have a database setup and when users click a button a Fragment Page pops up so they can edit the fields. I would like to try and have a sub-menu appear for comments (so they don't have to scroll all the way to the bottom of the screen).

Something like the Menu in the Material Gallery Sample would be great.

Note:

I am currently using **app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.Menu);** to open the Page Fragments.

Having both Fragments open side by side would be a usable options as well.

Thanks!

Here is an example diagram.

[image]

Comment: When you say it pops up do you mean it shows using showDialog, or just that it's shown on the page?

Comment: The idea would be that I open Fragment A (this has all the details for each entry). Then there is a button on Fragment A, when I click that I get Fragment B (this has all the comment history for the entry).

Comment: I'm still trying to understand if you mean open as in app.showDialog(), or open as in "make visible to the user". If you mean just make it visible, unfortunately that's not possible right now, because we don't allow view fragments inside view fragments. This is something that can be fixed in the future, the only reason for it is to avoid dependency loops, but obviously that's fixable.

Comment: Does this help make a little bit more sense of what I am trying to accomplish? I have all the components working as far as the comments section linking to the database entry. I am just trying to display them in two fragments rather than one tall one. [diagram](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4j0LGBj9cqBZC1GQ3dzbmRQams/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply. I'll put this as an answer because I think it will get you what you need. You could implement this if you put the page fragments directly into your page, and toggled their visible property to show/hide them.

The biggest trick here is how does the first page fragment tell the second to open? That ends up being simple, just add a custom boolean property to the first fragment. Then in the base page (which contains the two fragments) bind the visible property of the second fragment to the custom property of the first fragment. Then in the first fragment, you can set that property to "true" when you want the second fragment to show, and "false" when you want it to hide.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you!